# Symfony ManyToMany - Inquiry that retrieves all product attributes that belong to a given category

Tags: symfony, many-to-many

I have a problem with the query in many-to-many relationship.
I have a category table that has many-to-many relationships with the Products table, and the Products table has one-to-many relationships with the attributes category (one product can have many attributes). I want to do a query that will return all attributes of products in a given category to me, if any products are assigned to a given category then I want to download their attributes.

It seems to me that I should download records from the Attributes table repository, ie `$this` -> `getDoctrine`-> `getRespitory (Attribute :: class)` -> `getAllProductsAttributeInCategory ($ categoryId)`; and discard records with the `andWhere` function. I am interested in the `Id`, `name` and `value` from this table, but how can I check if the product of a given attribute is in a given category with many-to-many relation?

I perform the function in AttributeRepository:

```
public function getAllProductsAttributeInCategory($categoryId)
{
      return $this->createQueryBuilder('attr')
                 ->addSelect('attr')
                 ->innerJoin('attr.product', 'product') // Product table
                 ->addSelect('product')
                 ->andWhere('product.categories IN (:id)')->setParameter('id', $categoryId)
                 ->orderBy('a.name', 'ASC')
                 ->getQuery(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a product is in a specific category by joining on this specific category. Something like this:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('attr')
    ->join('attr.product', 'product')
    ->join('product.categories', 'category', Join::WITH, 'category.id = :cateogryId')
    ->setParameter('categoryId', $categoryId)
    ->orderBy('attr.name')
    ->getQuery()
;
```